# Selenium Chrome Driver doesn't work inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, arm

To give a little bit of context, I'm building an API using Python and Docker and I'm doing web scraping to multiple websites. It's important to mention that I recently changed my laptop to a M2 MacBook, it's important because the container used to work on every x64 processor but it doesn't work properly on arm architecture. I know that I can specify the platform in order to emulate linux/amd64 but for some reason the chrome driver doesn't work. Here is my docker-compose file and Dockerfile for reference and the error that my app returns:

**Docker Compose File**

```
version: '3.8'
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: UP_DB
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ****
      MYSQL_USER: ****
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - app-tier
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: UP_Adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - app-tier
  api:
    container_name: UP_API
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    volumes:
      - ./App:/SmartUP/App
    networks:
      - app-tier
  scrapper:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    container_name: UP_Scrapper
    image: ubuntu
    command: bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && wget http://api:5555/FetchGroupDataUPSite"
    volumes:
    - ./App:/SmartUP/App
    depends_on:
      - db
      - adminer
      - api
    networks:
      - app-tier
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10.7-buster
WORKDIR /SmartUP
COPY . .
ENV FLASK_ENV development
ENV DEBUG true
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
# Unzip the Chrome Driver into /usr/local/bin directory
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/
# Set display port as an environment variable
ENV DISPLAY=:99

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "App/run.py"]

# Makes the file executable
EXPOSE 5555
```

**Web Driver Config**

```
@dataclass
class ChromeBrowser:
    """Class to create a Chrome browser instance"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor method to initialize the Chrome browser instance"""
        self.chromeOptions = Options()
        self.chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")  # Ensure GUI is off
        self.chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        self.chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

    def buildBrowser(self) -> webdriver:
        """Method to build a Chrome browser instance"""
        webdriverService = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(
            service=webdriverService, options=self.chromeOptions)
        return browser
```

```
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
UP_API       | Stacktrace:
UP_API       | #0 0x004000724133 <unknown>
UP_API       | #1 0x004000458966 <unknown>
UP_API       | #2 0x00400048221a <unknown>
UP_API       | #3 0x00400047e07b <unknown>
UP_API       | #4 0x0040004bd9ad <unknown>
UP_API       | #5 0x0040004bd18f <unknown>
UP_API       | #6 0x0040004b49a3 <unknown>
UP_API       | #7 0x00400048946a <unknown>
UP_API       | #8 0x00400048a55e <unknown>
UP_API       | #9 0x0040006e3cae <unknown>
UP_API       | #10 0x0040006e78fe <unknown>
UP_API       | #11 0x0040006f0f20 <unknown>
UP_API       | #12 0x0040006e8923 <unknown>
UP_API       | #13 0x0040006bbc0e <unknown>
UP_API       | #14 0x00400070bb08 <unknown>
UP_API       | #15 0x00400070bc97 <unknown>
UP_API       | #16 0x00400071c113 <unknown>
UP_API       | #17 0x0040025effa3 start_thread
UP_API       |
UP_API       | #16 0x00400071c113 <unknown>
```

**I really hope that someone could help me, I've being stuck a whole week. In the worst scenario I will downgrade to my old pc**

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any particular experience with docker but what worked for me in command line based virtual machines was running the Chrome driver in headless mode, this can be done by adding the --headless flag to the ChromeOptions object in your Selenium script. I hope this helps.

Edit: in my answer I am assuming you downloaded your chrome driver from official sources: [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot to show my WebDriver config. Unfortunately, this config already worked on other systems, I think its docker related but thank you for trying :)